# How to remove an Embed Document from an Embed Document?

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I'm currently working on a project with Symfony 2 and MongoDB  and I'm facing a problem while removing an Embed Document using is ID.
I'm working with Activities. An Activity embed a list of Comment and list of Vote.
A Comment can embed a list of Vote too.

To remove a Comment or a Vote from an Activity I do stuff like that :

```
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
    $activity = $dm->getRepository('SocialNetworkActivityBundle:Activity')
                   ->findOneBy(array("votes.id" => $voteId));

    $votes = $activity->getVotes();
    $targetVote = null;
    foreach ($votes as $vote)
        if($vote->getId() == $voteId) {
            $targetVote = $vote;
            break;
        }
   $activity->removeVote($vote);
   $dm->flush();
```

First of all, I know that the method I use isn't the best so I'm looking for an alternative.
Second of all, I can't use that method to remove a Vote embed in a Comment embed in an Activity, so I'm looking for a way to do that.

I don't find any solution in Doctrine documentation or on Stack (or other forum).

If you have some clues or advises for me I'll be really glad to read about :D

Comment: Embedded documents do not have an id, which might be your problem.

Comment: I have a _id in my Embedded Document structure and it is visible in my mongo database. It just gives me the ability to identify each embed document.Why an Embedded Document couldn't have a _id ?